# testdisk - deleted partitions can be seen, but if I recover, will it wipe out existing partitions

Tags: testdisk, ntfsresize

I have a 170GB ntfs partition lost after ntfsresize(command) aborted, I restored the partition wrongly with testdisk, which shows, now a 205GB ntfs(with a exclamation mark) which may be including the deleted 11+10GB Linux partitions.
Now, I used testdisk again, and when "deeper search-ed, it shows the two linux partititions, swap and at the end, the ntfs 160GB partition as one 11GB partition and ~150GB partition. 
my doubt is, can I safely recover the 11GB and 150GB ntfs partition? will it bork the current Windows 7 partition and another existing partition as well as bootloader.
Here's a schematic diagram:

```
 |--sda1*(bootable ntfs C drive) --existing 
 |--sda2 (D partition) --existing 
 Extended partition 
 |Linux ext4 (Deleted) 10GB 
 |Linux ext4 (Deleted) 11GB 
 |swap (Deleted)
 |NTFS 160GB partition (Deleted)
```

Comment: I figured it out, at last after a couple of testdisk "deeper search". sneak into NTFS partitions and locate your windows partitions and order it correctly as bootable, primary and logical and write at once. don't choose "A" add partition.